# Is the $n/2$-th heat kernel coefficient topological?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, laplacian

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold, with $n$ *even* and consider the heat kernel of the Laplacian on $M$:
$$K_M(t) := \mathrm{Tr}\Big(\mathrm{e}^{-t \Delta_M}\Big) \equiv \sum_{\lambda\in\mathrm{spec}(\Delta_M)} \mathrm{e}^{-t \lambda}.$$
The heat kernel admits an asympotic small-$t$ expansion as
$$K_M(t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(M) t^k,$$
where $b_k(M)$ are known as the *heat kernel coefficients* and are given by integrals of local geometric data of $M$.

I am particularly interested in what I'll call *middle-dimensional heat kernel coefficient*, namely
$$ b_{n/2}(M) = b_{\mathrm{dim}M/2}(M).$$
This coefficient is interesting because it is closely related to the value of the Minakshisundaram-Pleijel zeta function (i.e. the spectral zeta function for the Laplacian) at zero.

Is an explicit formula for the calculation of $b_{n/2}(M)$ known? In particular, is it a topological invariant? It seems to me that it wants to be related to the number of connected components of $M$ or to some sum of Betti numbers of $M$, but I haven't managed to show it.

(If anyone feels brave, I'd be curious about how it generalizes to $p$-forms; namely what's the middle-dimensional heat kernel coefficient associated with the Laplacian, $\Delta_p = \mathrm{d}\delta + \delta \mathrm{d}$, acting on $p$-forms on $M$)

Comment: By the way, I feel the characterization middle-dimensional is idiotic but couldn't come up with a better short, descriptive term. Feel free to suggest.

Comment: Well, I've been told that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is called the "central binomial coefficient", but I also understood the "$n/2$-th" in your title immediately.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC well, it's central when they start at zero and finish at $2n$ (which is the case when $n$ is a non-negative integer). Would you call $\binom{2s}{s}$ central as well, for $s\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yeah, I don't even think it's that great a name, but when I posted a question about $\binom{2n}{n}$ I was told that that was how it was described. Just giving you a lead on existing terminology. Me, I'd accept it for the non-integral case equally well, but it's very much a case of personal taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some topologicality involving the middle-dimensional heat kernel coefficients but not as directly as I initially thought. The middle-dimensional heat kernel coefficients are themselves not topological, but alternating sums of them, for the Laplacian acting on different degree forms are. This was shown by [McKean & Singer](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-1/issue-1-2/Curvature-and-the-eigenvalues-of-the-Laplacian/10.4310/jdg/1214427880.full). Explicitly, if $b_k^{(p)}(M)$ is the $k$-th heat kernel coefficient associated with $\Delta_p := \mathrm{d}\delta + \delta\mathrm{d}:\Omega^p(M)\to\Omega^p(M)$, it holds:
$$\sum_{p=0}^{n} (-1)^p b_{n/2}^{(p)}(M) = \chi(M),$$
where $n=\dim M$.